# Using AutoCompleteTextView to change current dispaly page

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

There is a AutoCompleteTextView and when user write for-example blue and select it from AutoCompleteTextView, the current page change to that particular page.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private AutoCompleteTextView et_search_game;
    private TextView TextViewForAutoComplete;
    private static String[] GAMES_NAME = new String[] { "blue", "red", "black" };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //AutoCompleteTextView Setting.
        et_search_game = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.actv_search_game_name_xml);

        //TextView Setting.
        TextViewForAutoComplete = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_for_auto_complete_tv_xml);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterForGamesName = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, GAMES_NAME);

        et_search_game.setThreshold(1);
        et_search_game.setAdapter(arrayAdapterForGamesName);

        et_search_game.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(et_search_game.getText().toString().trim()=="blue"){
                    setContentView(R.xml.blue);
                } else if (et_search_game.getText().toString().trim()=="red"){
                    setContentView(R.xml.red);
                } else if (et_search_game.getText().toString().trim()=="black") {
                    setContentView(R.xml.black);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The red,black,blue pages are normal XML files in directory named 'xml'.

After running the code when i write b, the black row display and i click on it but nothing happen.

I don't want to go with activity(intent) method.
thanks.

Comment: Instead of "et_search_game.getText().toString().trim()" try taking the value from adapter with .equals("blue") and position from "i". It is a good practise to place layouts in layout directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of == use .equals

Instead of taking value from "et_search_game.getText().toString().trim()" you can take from adapter and position "i"

It is always a best practise to place layout xmls in "layout" directory